# Solving LPs by "inspection"?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Admittedly, this is a homework question but I just want to make sure my understanding of it is correct. I have the following:

> Maximize $z = x_{1}$
>
> $5x_{1} + x_{2}     = 4$
>
> $6x_{1} + x_{3}    = 8$
>
> $3x_{1} + x_{4}     = 3$
>
> where $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4} \geq 0$
>
> Solve the problem by inspection (do not use Gauss-Jordan row ops).

From what I see, this simply means that we have to increase $x_{1}$  to mazimize z so long as the constraints are met. I believe we can also do away with constraint 3 since it is redundant? However, the constraints were given as inequalities. I'm a bit confused as to how the answer is supposed to look if I am not alloed to derive new rows from this. $x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4}$ are of course slack variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that for each of the equalities, $x_1$ will need to be less the larger you make $x_2$ $x_3$ or $x_4.$ So try setting $x_2,x_3,x_4$ equal to zero. The smallest of the three values you get for $x_1$ will be the best you can do and you can always satisfy it.

Comment: Ah I see. I just needed to think about it differently. Thanks!